# A complex update in GORM

Tags: database, go, orm, go-gorm

I have a model in GORM with Postgres as database. The model is like this

```
type Country struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name   string
    Population int64
    Regions []Region
}

type Region struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name   string
    Cities []City
    CountryID uint `sql:"type:bigint REFERENCES countries(id) ON DELETE CASCADE" json:"-"`
}

type City struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string
    Comment string
    RegionID   uint `sql:"type:bigint REFERENCES regions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE" json:"-"`
}
```

When I create a new record from model, I invoke create function

```
db.Create(&menu)
```

Now, I'm trying to update the model and I have some issues.
If I invoke this

```
err = db.Debug().Where("id = ?", countryId).Updates(&country).Error
```

I have an error an the model is not updated in database
UPDATED:
The error is

```
(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:100) 
[2020-06-06 02:37:59]  sql: converting argument $4 type: unsupported type []main.Region, a slice of struct 

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:100) 
[2020-06-06 02:37:59]  [0.00ms]  UPDATE "" SET "created_at" = '2020-06-06 00:37:50', "id" = 1, "name" = 'New Name', "regions" = '[{{1 2020-06-06 00:37:50.450497 +0000 UTC 2020-06-06 00:37:50.450497 +0000 UTC <nil>} Region 1 [{{1 2020-06-06 00:37:50.465029 +0000 UTC 2020-06-06 00:37:50.465029 +0000 UTC <nil>} City 1  1}] 1} {{0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>} Region 2 updated [{{0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>} City 2 updated  0}] 0}]', "updated_at" = '2020-06-06 00:37:50'  WHERE (id = 1)  
[0 rows affected or returned ]
```

If I run

```
err = db.Debug().Model(&country).Association("Regions").Replace(country.Regions).Error
```

The regions and cities models are updated in database but country model is not updated.
Added to this, for regions model during update delete elements has null for CountryID but cities model doesn't update its RegionID to dereference.

How can I update a complete model like this?

UPDATE:

I don't know how to update a complete Country model.
This is the full queries executed.

```
Create Tables

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:35) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:29]  [36;1m[20.02ms]  CREATE TABLE "countries" ("id" serial,"created_at" timestamp with time zone,"updated_at" timestamp with time zone,"deleted_at" timestamp with time zone,"name" text,"population" bigint , PRIMARY KEY ("id"))  
[36;31m[0 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:35) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:29]  [36;1m[16.00ms]  CREATE INDEX idx_countries_deleted_at ON "countries"(deleted_at)   
[36;31m[0 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:36) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:29]  [36;1m[28.99ms]  CREATE TABLE "regions" ("id" serial,"created_at" timestamp with time zone,"updated_at" timestamp with time zone,"deleted_at" timestamp with time zone,"name" text,"country_id" bigint REFERENCES countries(id) ON DELETE CASCADE , PRIMARY KEY ("id"))  
[36;31m[0 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:36) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:29]  [36;1m[11.99ms]  CREATE INDEX idx_regions_deleted_at ON "regions"(deleted_at)   
[36;31m[0 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:37) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:29]  [36;1m[18.99ms]  CREATE TABLE "cities" ("id" serial,"created_at" timestamp with time zone,"updated_at" timestamp with time zone,"deleted_at" timestamp with time zone,"name" text,"comment" text,"region_id" bigint REFERENCES regions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE , PRIMARY KEY ("id"))  
[36;31m[0 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:37) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:29]  [36;1m[32.00ms]  CREATE INDEX idx_cities_deleted_at ON "cities"(deleted_at)   
[36;31m[0 rows affected or returned ] 
Add Country Model

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:64) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:32]  [36;1m[3.99ms]  INSERT INTO "countries" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","population") VALUES ('2020-06-06 01:33:32','2020-06-06 01:33:32',NULL,'Country 1',0) RETURNING "countries"."id"  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:64) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:32]  [36;1m[4.00ms]  INSERT INTO "regions" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","country_id") VALUES ('2020-06-06 01:33:32','2020-06-06 01:33:32',NULL,'Region 1',1) RETURNING "regions"."id"  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:64) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:32]  [36;1m[3.00ms]  INSERT INTO "cities" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","comment","region_id") VALUES ('2020-06-06 01:33:32','2020-06-06 01:33:32',NULL,'City 1','',1) RETURNING "cities"."id"  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:64) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:32]  [36;1m[4.00ms]  INSERT INTO "regions" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","country_id") VALUES ('2020-06-06 01:33:32','2020-06-06 01:33:32',NULL,'Region 2',1) RETURNING "regions"."id"  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:64) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:32]  [36;1m[3.83ms]  INSERT INTO "cities" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","comment","region_id") VALUES ('2020-06-06 01:33:32','2020-06-06 01:33:32',NULL,'City 2','',2) RETURNING "cities"."id"  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]
Update Country Model

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:75) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[3.99ms]  SELECT * FROM "countries"  WHERE "countries"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ((id = 1))  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:75) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[4.00ms]  SELECT * FROM "regions"  WHERE "regions"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (("country_id" IN (1)))  
[36;31m[2 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:75) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[3.00ms]  SELECT * FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (("region_id" IN (1,2)))  
[36;31m[2 rows affected or returned ]
{{1 2020-06-05 23:33:32.660156 +0000 UTC 2020-06-05 23:33:32.660156 +0000 UTC <nil>} Country 1 0 [{{1 2020-06-05 23:33:32.664151 +0000 UTC 2020-06-05 23:33:32.664151 +0000 UTC <nil>} Region 1 [{{1 2020-06-05 23:33:32.668156 +0000 UTC 2020-06-05 23:33:32.668156 +0000 UTC <nil>} City 1  1}] 1} {{2 2020-06-05 23:33:32.672155 +0000 UTC 2020-06-05 23:33:32.672155 +0000 UTC <nil>} Region 2 [{{2 2020-06-05 23:33:32.676156 +0000 UTC 2020-06-05 23:33:32.676156 +0000 UTC <nil>} City 2  2}] 1}]}

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:99) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[3.00ms]  UPDATE "regions" SET "created_at" = '2020-06-05 23:33:32', "updated_at" = '2020-06-06 01:33:39', "deleted_at" = NULL, "name" = 'Region 1', "country_id" = 1  WHERE "regions"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "regions"."id" = 1  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

() 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[6.00ms]  UPDATE "cities" SET "created_at" = '2020-06-05 23:33:32', "updated_at" = '2020-06-06 01:33:39', "deleted_at" = NULL, "name" = 'City 1', "comment" = '', "region_id" = 1  WHERE "cities"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "cities"."id" = 1  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:99) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[4.00ms]  SELECT * FROM "countries"  WHERE "countries"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "countries"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "countries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:99) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[3.00ms]  UPDATE "regions" SET "created_at" = '2020-06-05 23:33:32', "updated_at" = '2020-06-06 01:33:39', "deleted_at" = NULL, "name" = 'Region 1', "country_id" = 1  WHERE "regions"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "regions"."id" = 1  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

() 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[4.99ms]  UPDATE "cities" SET "created_at" = '2020-06-05 23:33:32', "updated_at" = '2020-06-06 01:33:39', "deleted_at" = NULL, "name" = 'City 1', "comment" = '', "region_id" = 1  WHERE "cities"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "cities"."id" = 1  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:99) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[4.00ms]  INSERT INTO "regions" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","country_id") VALUES ('2020-06-06 01:33:39','2020-06-06 01:33:39',NULL,'Region 2 updated',1) RETURNING "regions"."id"  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

() 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[3.99ms]  INSERT INTO "cities" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","comment","region_id") VALUES ('2020-06-06 01:33:39','2020-06-06 01:33:39',NULL,'City 2 updated','',3) RETURNING "cities"."id"  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:99) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[3.00ms]  SELECT * FROM "countries"  WHERE "countries"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "countries"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "countries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]

(C:/source/go/gorm/country.go:99) 
[2020-06-06 01:33:39]  [36;1m[3.99ms]  UPDATE "regions" SET "country_id" = NULL  WHERE "regions"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (("id" NOT IN (1,3)) AND ("country_id" = 1))  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ]
```

Comment: Add the error you are getting and executed queries from console please

Comment: @Eklavya question is updated with queries executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For update existing data you can fetch first preloading child

```
var country Country
db.Preload("Regions").Preload("Regions.Cities").First(&country, 1)
```

Then you can update the data and add new data  like

```
country.Regions[0].Cities[0].Name = "Dhaka City 1"
country.Regions[0].Name = "Dhaka Region 1"
country.Regions[1].Cities = append(country.Regions[1].Cities, City{Name: "Dhaka City 2"})
```

Now save the updated data in database

```
db.Save(&country)
```

If you want to add new child data only you can avoid Preload also.

```
db.First(&country, 8)
country.Regions = append(country.Regions, Region{Name: "Dhaka Region 3"})
db.Save(&country)
```

By default gorm `association_autoupdate` flag set as `true`, so it's auto save association.

```
err = db.Debug().Model(&country).Association("Regions").Replace(country.Regions).Error
```

Replace only replace the association means with other. If you don't give any it will just remove current association with `Country` here. And only `Regions` not it's child city.

Gorm doesn't support any delete operation on update. It just use for add or update existing data.
Gorm model uses soft delete by default. If you delete Regions this way, it will update the `deleted_at` field data. And when query it always filter out deleted data.

```
db.Delete(county.Regions)
```

And it won't soft delete City, you have to do this way.

```
db.Delete(region.Cities)
```

A working code sample [here](https://play.golang.org/p/HNX0k5FwgMG)

Comment: County = Country There is a typo

Comment: I added some explanation here

Comment: Thanks @Eklavya. Based on your sample I have created this https://play.golang.com/p/lzR5h_pq7gU. As you can see, when I run  UpdateRemoveOneCityFromLastRegion function, nothing is remove from Cities

Comment: @J19 Yes Update won't delete data, that exactly I explained

Comment: Thans @Eklavya. I think gorm is a toy orm comparing with orms in other platforms like java on dot net.

Comment: Gorm is one of the best orm in go I experienced, it needs time to mature enough like other.

Comment: It could be, I don't have a deep lnowledge in gorm but a common scenario like i have describes is really usual and it's difficult to manage