# Gorm not adhering to many2many specifier

Tags: mysql, go, many-to-many, go-gorm

I am having issues with Go's Gorm.

I have a table called **scopes** and a table called **employees**.
I also have a many2many/intermediary table called **employee_scopes**.

When I am trying to save the employee with the specified scopes. I get an an error that Gorm is trying to insert the record into the intermediary table as if it was the scopes table.

Error Message:
*Error 1054: Unknown column 'scope' in 'field list'*

Models:

```
type Employee struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName  string           `json:"FirstName"  gorm:"column:first_name;type:varchar(100);not null"`
    Scopes     []EmployeeScope  `json:"Scopes"     gorm:"many2many:employee_scopes"`
}

type EmployeeScope struct {
    gorm.Model
    Scope     string            `json:"Scope" `
}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees`
(
    ID                    INT(6)              AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name            VARCHAR(100)        NOT NULL,
    created_at            TIMESTAMP           NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    deleted_at            TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at            TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
);

CREATE TABLE `scopes`
(
    id         INT(6)              AUTO_INCREMENT,
    scope      VARCHAR(100)        UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP           NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE `employee_scopes`
(
    id          INT(6)     AUTO_INCREMENT,
    employee_id INT(6)     NOT NULL,
    scope_id    INT(6)     NOT NULL,
    created_at  TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    deleted_at  TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at  TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (scope_id) REFERENCES scopes (id)
);
```

It's like Gorm is not listening to what I am specifying. I tried to add the back-reference, with the correct specifier, and I get the same error. I also added the many 2 many overrides, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error Message: Error 1054: Unknown column 'scope' in 'field list'

Because of gorm use Table name as the pluralized version of the struct name ([Ref](http://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Pluralized-Table-Name)). Thats why gorm try to insert data into `employee_scopes` table. Your `EmployeeScope` struct name should be `Scope`.

```
type Employee struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName  string           `json:"FirstName"  gorm:"column:first_name;type:varchar(100);not null"`
    Scopes     []Scope          `json:"Scopes"     gorm:"many2many:employee_scopes"`
}

type Scope struct {
    gorm.Model
    Scope     string            `json:"Scope" `
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I now have a problem that Gorm wants to insert the existing records into the scopes table. What should I do so that Gorm auto-resolve ids from scopes names that I add to a slice?

Comment: Gorm don't auto-resolve ids, you can send ids of scope as requestbody and fetch those scope and set in Employee for existing record, you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62263328/4207306